# XXX does not does not support provisioning profiles in azure build pipeline

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm building an Ionic 4 application in Azure build pipeline. When I try to run pipeline that has other cordova dependencies I'm getting the errors below during the Xcode archive step.

```
❌  error: AppAuth does not support provisioning profiles. AppAuth does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile Beta2020 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: GoogleUtilities does not support provisioning profiles. GoogleUtilities does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile Beta2020 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: GoogleToolboxForMac does not support provisioning profiles. GoogleToolboxForMac does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile Beta2020 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'GoogleToolboxForMac' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: GTMSessionFetcher does not support provisioning profiles. GTMSessionFetcher does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile Beta2020 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: GTMAppAuth does not support provisioning profiles. GTMAppAuth does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile Beta2020 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: nanopb does not support provisioning profiles. nanopb does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile  Beta2020 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: Protobuf does not support provisioning profiles. Protobuf does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile  Beta2020 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: Pods-xx does not support provisioning profiles. Pods-xx does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile  Beta2020 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'Pods-xx' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: FBSDKShareKit does not support provisioning profiles. FBSDKShareKit does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile Beta2020 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'FBSDKShareKit' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: FBSDKLoginKit does not support provisioning profiles. FBSDKLoginKit does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile Beta2020 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'FBSDKLoginKit' from project 'Pods')
```

there was a same issue while running build pipeline with ionic 3 code base as well but there was a solution to run script below at start of the pipeline

```
echo "Uninstalling all CocoaPods versions..."
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -ax
echo "Installing CocoaPods version 1.5.3..."
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.5.3
```

[Source](https://microsoft.github.io/azure-pipelines-image-generation/cocoapods-pod-does-not-support-provisioning-profiles/)

but this solution is not working with ionic 4 code base.

cordova plugins:

```
"plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-globalization": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepicker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V13_VERSION": "27.+",
        "FCM_VERSION": "17.0.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.10.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "com.googleusercontent.apps.123456789101112-abcd1234abcd1234zbcd1234abcd1234"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "123456789012345",
        "APP_NAME": "my_app",
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "5.13.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
        "GMS_VERSION": "16.0.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-localization-strings": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V7_VERSION": "27.+",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the workaround mentioned in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419956/how-to-fix-pod-does-not-support-provisioning-profiles-in-azure-devops-build) with similar issue .

Add the following code to your `podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please tell the right place to put this in an Ionic app as I do not deal with `podfile` directly? @Hugh Lin - MSFT

Comment: I specified `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No` arguments in xcode task and it worked, but now I am getting error while uploading the ipa file to app store. 
`ERROR ITMS-90174: "Missing Provisioning Profile - Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision."`

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this @RageshPikalmunde? It would be ideal if we could tell Azure to ignore the frameworks and just sign the app