# ERROR ITMS-90174: "Missing Provisioning Profile - Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision."

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic4, azure-pipelines, provisioning-profile

I am working on an Azure DevOps build pipeline, I am building an ionic 4 app through the pipeline and it's getting build fine but when I try to upload the `.ipa` to app store through release pipeline of Azure DevOps I am getting

```
ERROR ITMS-90174: "Missing Provisioning Profile - Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision."
```

I am aware as there is  [already a question available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972472/error-itms-90174-missing-provisioning-profile-ios-apps-must-contain-a-provis) on the forum but it's not ok with my scenario.

I added `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No` in argument of xcode task in build pipeline and that helps to build the app otherwise it throws an  [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749672/xxx-does-not-does-not-support-provisioning-profiles-in-azure-build-pipeline)

I have added `build.json` file already

```
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "buildFlag": [
                "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
            ]
        },
        "release": {
            "buildFlag": [
                "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to build the app with `--buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"` but it's not helping me out.

command tried:

```
cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
cordova build ios --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

though there is a solution for manual upload:

```
when you upload the archive to App Store (for TestFlight or App Store), you need to select "manually 
 manage signing" and then select the right distribution profile.
```

but not useful in my case.

Comment: Do you get this issue in the `Apple App Store Releas` task? You could check if the `embedded.mobileprovision` exists  and the file location. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41015902/13464420), the file needs to exist in root of folder. If it doesn't exist, you could use `Copy file` task to copy the file to the root before packing.

Comment: Please check if [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336059/issues-with-publishing-ios-app-to-testflight-through-azure-devops) could give you some ideas. You may share build definition or yaml file.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I got your point of using `copy task` to add  `embedded.mobileprovision` but I how I can copy it in a `payload folder` before Xcode task which make archive..and also after the archive is done is there any way to copy the file into the ipa without any damage??

Comment: You could add the copy file task before the pack step(e.g. publish artifacts). Then the file could be added to the root folder in the package. On the other hand, maybe you can share some build definitions, which will help us understand your process.